# SPGridView HeaderStyle Background

Tags: spgridview

All,

I am trying to find the styles for the SPGridView HeaderStyle.  It doesn't seem to work when i apply the following:

```
        spGridView.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        spGridView.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

It looks very strange.  I have filtered columns and sort only columns.  The sort only columns show up with no background, and the sort only columns show up somewhat okay, but they have a border where the dropdown for the filter context menu should be.

How do I fix this? 
See the image in this URL (I couldn't post it because I am a new user and they require i add more points):

http://spgridview.com/files/2-26-2012%2011-57-51%20PM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did, it seemed to work.

But i know its not the final answer.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-viewheadertr th{
padding-top:0px;
background-color:#2878C0;
color:White;
}
.ms-viewheadertr .ms-vh2-gridview{
height:auto;
background-color:#2878C0;
color:White;
}

.ms-menuimagecell{
border:0px;
}

.ms-vh .ms-menuimagecell,.ms-vh2 .ms-menuimagecell,.ms-vh-icon .ms-menuimagecell{
border:0px;
}

.ms-vh .ms-menuimagecell img,.ms-vh2 .ms-menuimagecell img,.ms-vh-icon .ms-menuimagecell img{
border:0px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe It's not what you are looking for, I'm just sharing. I used this styles in all of my project whenever I utilize SPGridView to display data.

```
 Style="border-bottom-style: none; border-right-style: none; width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse; border-top-style: none; border-left-style: none;"
        CssClass="ms-listviewtable"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="ms-viewheadertr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="ms-itmhover"
        RowStyle-CssClass="ms-itmhover" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="s4-itm-selected" RowStyle-Height="25"
```

Answer (score 1):

Bill's answer worked for me.

In our application page, we need to override styles coming from Core.css which is shown in Bill's answer.

Comment: This section is for answers only